# function in php returns different result with same parameters in loop and outside of loop

Tags: php

I have a nested loop in which the outer loop gets an item from the array and then the inner loop runs a function on each item of a different array. The problem is that inside these loops the function returns a different value for two parameters but if I just copy these values by printing it to the screen and then separately on the file it returns a different result.

I tried to print each iteration of the loop echoing the function call in a string with parameter as variables being printed and then running the function like below:

```
echo "str_accur($dbBookTitle[$i], {$bookDataInfo[$j][0]}, false): ";
echo str_accur($dbBookTitle[$i], $bookDataInfo[$j][0], false);
```

here inside the loop it shows different result:

> str_accur( Cyber-Physical Systems, ApplicationAnalysisToolsforASIPDes, false): 21

As you can see the 21 is the result of the function and then I will copy that function and try it separately like this

```
echo str_accur("Cyber-Physical Systems", "ApplicationAnalysisToolsforASIPDes", false);
```

with the same parameter it is returning 9. which i expect but why in a loop it prints 21 is beyond me.

Here is the loop:

```
for($i = 1;$i < $dbDataLen;$i++){
    echo "from database index ({$i}): " . $dbBookTitle[$i];
    for($j = 0;$j < $bdiL;$j++){
        if($bookDataInfo[$j][0] == "False"){
            $class = 'w3-red';
        }else{
            $class = 'w3-green';
        }
        echo "<p class='$class'>bookDataInfo index ($j) : {$bookDataInfo[$j][0]}</p>";
        echo "str_accur($dbBookTitle[$i], {$bookDataInfo[$j][0]}, false): ";
        echo str_accur($dbBookTitle[$i], $bookDataInfo[$j][0], false);
        echo "<hr>";
    }
}
```

The actual data and the source code for str_accur are large so i don't know if should display it here but I put it on GitHub just in case.
https://github.com/siyaddigital/phpFuncProblem

Comment: `var_dump();` is your friend. Without knowing what `str_accur()` looks like then it impossible to blame it on the data.

Comment: `str_accur( Cyber` I'm confused about that whitespace. try `trim()` for your arguments

Comment: "_with the same parameter it is returning 9. which i expect but why in a loop it prints 21 is beyond me._" - Because you are _not_ passing the same parameters, there must be some difference.

Comment: I clone from github repo, and when I run the code on application-fns.php it returns 9. Same is the output in index.php. Are you sure you are looking at the right output ? -- Output--

bookDataInfo index (45) : ApplicationAnalysisToolsforASIPDes
str_accur(Cyber-Physical Systems, ApplicationAnalysisToolsforASIPDes, false): 9

Comment: The functions appear to be deterministic, so any variation in the result must be due to variation in the input. You're comparing strings by character in those function. I have to assume the string from the database is different than the string literal you're testing with. Echoing the string in HTML is not the best way to examine it. There are many things you won't be able to see that way. Use var_dump as suggested above.

Comment: So can it possible something is wrong with my machine, is that even possible.i am copying this from my browser: bookDataInfo index (45) : ApplicationAnalysisToolsforASIPDes

str_accur( Cyber-Physical Systems, ApplicationAnalysisToolsforASIPDes, false): 21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out white space is changing the function output big time, I needed to trim the parameters and browser already trimming the values by default before printing them:

```
str_accur(trim($trgStr), trim($mtchTo), false);
```